# Create Pivot table for each column in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I have many columns (there is one dependent variable and many independent variables)

| variable_id | dep_var | variable_1 | variable_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| new | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| new | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| new | 0 | 8 | 7 |
| new | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| new | 0 | 17 | 9 |
| new | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I want to create a Pivot table such as this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['variable_1'], columns=['dep_var'], values=['variable_id'],aggfunc='count')
```

I want to create it for each column separatly (so I need to change index in pd.pivot_table)

I have written a sample code:

```
def pivot_table(df):
    df_columns = list(df)
    for column in df_columns:
        print("indexing by: ", column) 
        print(pd.pivot_table(df,index=[column], columns=['dep_var'], values=['variable_id'],aggfunc='count'))
```

but I want my result to be saved as pandas DataFrame

desired output:
[how I want my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW72m.png) for each variable separately

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def pivot_table(df):
    dfs = []
    for column in df:
        print("indexing by: ", column) 
        df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=[column], values=['dep_var'])
        dfs.append(df)
    return dfs
```

Comment: it returns an error when it hits dep_var
ValueError: Grouper for 'dep_var' not 1-dimensional
do you know any solution for this?

Comment: @artur - it is data realted problem. So not easy find problem. If need found it need debug first 10 rows, then 20... and last found error. But still not clear what need from question. Best is create some sample dta anad expected ouput from this data in EDIted question

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't return a normal pivot, it just returns some strange result

Comment: @artur - how looks your expected ouput? Can you add to question?

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: Not understand, how looks good and bad ouput.